# toLocaleString resets value after 5 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Summary:** I am creating a form that has many inputs, some of which should only take *only* an integer value. These inputs have the class `int-val`, which I reference in my Js.

I am setting up the int inputs to have commas after every third integer on `keyup`. I've succeeded in doing so, but now `this.value` resets after the fourth character on `keyup` and I'm not sure why.

**Effort:** This is what my code looks like:

```
function addComma(x) {
   return x.toLocaleString('en');
}

// add function to int inputs
$('.int-val').keyup(function (e) {
   let val = parseFloat(this.value);
   this.value = addComma(val);
   console.log(this.value);
}
```

In the console, the output for '4500000' is this:

```
4
45
450
4,500
4 // if adding a fifth character, this.value resets to the first character entered
```

This is turning out to be more difficult than I expected. Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are parsing the localized number `4,500` and `,` is not supported, so `parseFloat` throws away everything after the unsupported char (*the `,`*).

There is no built in method to parse localized numbers.

For this specific localization you use, you could do  `parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g,''));` and you would work around the problem.

```js
function addComma(x) {
  return x.toLocaleString('en');
}

// add function to int inputs
$('.int-val').keyup(function(e) {
  let val = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  this.value = addComma(val);
  console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="int-val" />
```

You still have to handle decimals and empty strings.

---

Have a look at https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize for a more robust approach